# Include all files and folder inside a folder and exclude a specific sub folder with rsync

Tags: rsync

I have a deployment script which uses rsync with filter that uses a .txt file to merge. How can I include everything inside /web while excluding the folder /web/uploads? I'm using Bitbucket pipelines to deploy.

`--filter=merge ${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}/bitbucket-pipelines-filter.txt`

I have tried the following rules:

```
+ /web/***
- /web/uploads
```

But for some reason rsync keeps emptying the uploads folder since it is empty in the repository. All other things go as expected. All files inside the web folder are being uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include/Exclude/Filter rules apply from left to right (or in a file, from top to bottom). So to "*include everything inside `/web` while excluding the folder `/web/uploads`*" you need to exclude `uploads` before including everything else. And because the default action of `rsync` is to include everything you don't actually need to specify that:

```
rsync --dry-run -avP --exclude '/web/uploads/' /from/path/  rHost:/to/path
```

The leading `/` on `/web/uploads/` ties the pattern to the top of the tree being transferred. (In the example's case that would be the directory `/from/path/web/uploads`.) The trailing `/` declares the pattern as being a directory.